# Склонение имен собственных

Tags: имена-собственные

Склоняются ли фамилии: *Пригодич, Капелько, Жук, Нога* и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Мужские фамилии Пригодич и Жук склоняются, женские — нет: они кончаются согласной буквой.

Фамилия Капелько не склоняется: она кончается буквой "о".

Фамилия Нога склоняется: она кончается буквой "а" после согласного, а происхождение этой фамилии — явно не французское.

Answer (score 1):

муж. Пригодич, Жук - склоняются
жен. Пригодич, Жук - не склоняются.

муж. и жен. Капелько - не склоняется (окончание на -о)

Не склоняется фамилия Нога, если ударение падает на -а.

Если ударение на 1 слог фамилия Нога может склоняться, а может и не склоняться (хотя более предпочтительным является склоняемый вариант)

Comment: >Не склоняется фамилия Нога, если ударение падает на -а.  

Это не так. Не склоняются только французские фамилии на ударную -а/-я. Да и то - больше по традиции. Славянские - склоняются. В остальных случаях чаще склоняются, хотя возможны колебания в норме или сама норма оспаривается. 

>Если ударение на 1 слог фамилия Нога может склоняться

Всегда сколоняется.

Answer (score 0):

Фамилия *Капелько*, скорее всего, украинского происхождения и в украинском языке она склоняется. А в русском - нет.